# How to make jagged indexer

Tags: c#, indexer

I have seen jagged indexers somewhere and would like to know how to make them work.

I know I can do the following:

```
class foo
{
    public string this[int i1]
    {
        get{ return GetString(i1); }
    }

    public string this[int i1, int i2]
    {
        get{ return GetString(i1) + GetString(i2); }
    }
}
```

So that:

```
string s1 = foo[5];
string s2 = foo[12,8];
```

The question is, how do I define the indexer to do...

```
string s2 = foo[12][8];
```

If possible (and otherwise unclear), I would also appreciate the setter definition.

```
foo[12][8] = "qwerty";
```

Comment: As ItzWarty said, just return an indexed instance (could be array or nested class) from the first indexer.

Answer (score 4):

Derrick Shepard's answer seems correct, however I had a few notes for you:

With your current methods:

```
public string this[int i1]
public string this[int i1, int i2]
```

`foo[12][8]` would parse equivalently to `(foo[12])[8]`; you'd be getting `string foo[12]` and then getting it's 9th character.

If you're willing to change your first method (the indexer with a single argument), you could consider returning an object which would, in turn, provide another indexer.

Comment: The evaluation is helpful but I don't see how to implement it. Isn't it possible to have both indexers at once, so that the following are both valid: `string s1 = foo[5];` and `string s2 = foo[12][8];`

Comment: There are ways to do it via implicit cast from indexer object to string, but I think most people would consider that non-conventional... and just really strange.  IMO it would hurt the readability of your code for essentially little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
class foo
{
    private string[][] collection = new string[2][];

    public string[] this[int index]
    {
        get
        { 
            return collection[index]; 
        }
        set
        {
            collection[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
string s1 = foo[1][0];
foo[1][0] = s1;
```

I was happy when I founded this but personally for me is quite confusing because getter and setter are weird. It looks like if collection is 1D array and not jagged.